# Syncing new data with Contentful - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, contentful

I am trying to use the syncing feature of contentful so I will only fetch new or updated content form my space.  From the documentation it says with the fetch I need a parameter of "initial"="true", which I am trying below, but I get 400 error.  Has someone used this before?  thanks

```
[self.client fetchEntriesMatching:@{@"content_type": @"navigationPage",
                                        @"locale":countryCode,
                                        @"initial":@"true"

                                        }
                              success:^(CDAResponse *response, CDAArray *array) {



                          } failure:^(CDAResponse *response, NSError *error) {


                          }];
```

`

Comment: have you tried simply `curl`ing the data or using some rest client? And what other response do you receive, probably not just a 400.

Comment: Have you printed out the error to gather more information?

Comment: Maybe use a boolean value of `true` instead of a string `@"true"` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the entirely wrong method. You should be calling the `initialSynchronizationWithSuccess:failure:`which is documented here http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ContentfulDeliveryAPI/1.10.4/Classes/CDAClient.html#//api/name/initialSynchronizationWithSuccess:failure:

That will in turn call the sync endpoint of the Contentful API with the initial parameter set to true. It will return a `CDASyncedSpace` object that can be used for further requests. Documented here http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ContentfulDeliveryAPI/1.10.4/Classes/CDASyncedSpace.html